# Applying CustomAttribute value for multiple users in Office 365

Tags: c#, powershell, outlook, office365

I created PowerShell script for applying a custom attribute value as some string. But it needs to apply to only six users within the organization. When I am using for loop we are getting an exception like the following:

> Connecting to remote server ps.outlook.com failed with the following
>   error message : The request is not serviced on the server. Your
>   request is too frequent. Please wait for few minutes and retry
>   again.[ClientAccessServer=BLUPR16CA0052,BackEndServer=blupr18mb0465.namprd18.prod.outlook.com,RequestId=d0a76f19-fc52-4d6c-9701-50015b8fd18e,TimeStamp=4/29/2016
>   1:36:37 PM] [FailureCategory=FailFast-BySelf]  For more information,
>   see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic."}

Hear is the code which i tried:-

```
for (int k = 0; k <= i; k++)
                {

                    try
                    {
                        using (Runspace psRunSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo))
                        {                  
                            psRunSpace.Open();                             
                            var pipe = psRunSpace.CreatePipeline();             
                            Command NewAddressList = new Command("Set-Mailbox");
                            NewAddressList.Parameters.Add((new CommandParameter("Identity", userList5[k].Properties["Displayname"].Value.ToString())));
                            NewAddressList.Parameters.Add((new CommandParameter("CustomAttribute15", "LicenceActivated")));
                            pipe.Commands.Add(NewAddressList);
                            Collection<PSObject> NewAddressListResult = pipe.Invoke();
                            pipe.Dispose();
                            userListgroupmembers = NewAddressListResult;                          
                            psRunSpace.Close();
                        }

                    }
```

Comment: How are you doing your loop? If you are sending separate requests perhaps you can collect an array of users and execute it once. Either way we need to see the code.

Comment: Hi Matt, i just edited my question. I added my code which i tried please check once.